# R: Winsorizing (robust HD) not compatible with NAs?

Tags: r, na, outliers

I want to use the winsorize function provided in the "robustHD" Package but it does not seem to work with NA's as can be seen in the example

```
## generate data
set.seed(1234)     # for reproducibility
x <- rnorm(10)     # standard normal
x[1] <- x[1] * 10  # introduce outlier

x[11]<- NA ## adding NA

## winsorize data
x
winsorize(x)
```

I googled the problem but didn't find a solution or even anyone with a similar problem. Is winsorizing might considered as a "bad" technique or how can you explain this lack of information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some maybe useful thoughts:

1. Stack Overflow is a programming board, where programming related questions are asked and answers are given. For question whether or not certain statistical procedures are appropriate or considered "bad", you are more likely to find knowledgable people on crossvalidated.
2. A statistical method and the implementation of a statistical method into a certain software environment are often rather independent. That is to say that if the developer of a package has not included certain features (e.g `NA` handling) into his package, this does not mean much for the method per se. Having said that, of course it can. The only way to be sure whether the omission of a package feature was intentional is to actually ask the developer of the package. If the question is more geared towards statistics and the validity of the method in the presence of missing values, crossvalidated is likely to be more helpful.
3. I don't know why you can't find any information on this topic. I can confidently say though that this is the very first time I have heard the term "winsorized". I actually had to look it up, and I can surely say that I have never encountered this approach, and I would personally never use it.

A simple solution to your problem from a computational point of view would be to omit all incomplete cases before you start working with the function. It also makes intuitive sense that cases with missing values cannot be easily winsorized. First, the computation of the mean and standard deviation would have to be done on the complete cases anyway, and then it is unclear which value to assign to those with missing values since they may not necessarily be outliers, even though they could be.

If omitting incomplete cases is not an option for you, you may want to look for imputation methods (on CV).

Comment: Yes I realized that this might be the wrong forum. I'm trying to delete all the NA's and subsequently use the winsorize function. but what i'm struggling in general is to perform a task (i.e. split dataframe --> perform required task (maybe on a subset) and put everything back together in the same order as it was. Most of my code problems lie in "putting it back together" and i guess this is probably the most common problem for people new to a programming language (S) or even new to the whole field.

Comment: In your case, did you try `complete.cases`? Otherwise, for so-called `split-apply-combine`-routines, Hadley Wickham's packages tend (in my humble opinion) to be very convenient. Try for instance `plyr`. Other packages such as `dplyr` or `data.table` are a bit faster, but the syntax is less R-ish, so it takes more time to learn how to use them.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I'm trying the plyr with the ddply function as it seems quite intuitive but i'm struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a vector to winsorize, the `winsor2` function defined [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/winsorization/) can be easily modified by setting `na.rm = TRUE` for the `median` and `mad` functions in the code. That provides the same functionality as winsorize{robustHD} with 1 difference: `winsorize` calls `robStandardize`, which includes some adjustment for very small values. I don't understand what it's doing, so caveat emptor if you forgo it.

If you want to winsorize the individual columns of a matrix (as opposed to the multivariate winsorization using a tolerance ellipse available as another option in `winsorize`) you should be able to poach the necessary code from `winsorize.default` and `standardize`. They do the same thing as `winsor2` but in matrix form. Again, you need to add your own `na.rm = TRUE` settings into the functions as needed.